# matlab: given a prefix string, how to generate a sequence

Tags: matlab

For example, the prefix string is 'fig', I want to have a new string with the sequence 'fig1,fig2,fig3,...,fig100', how to do this conveniently without using a for loop? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want a cell array of strings, i.e. `{'fig1','fig2',...'}`

Here's one of many ways to achieve this (change the format string to `'fig%03i'` if you want the output to be `'fig001','fig002'` etc):

```
figString = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('fig%i',x),1:100,'uniformOutput',false)
```

---

**EDIT**

If you only want a single string, i.e. `'fig1,fig2, ...'`, the easiest solution is to use `sprintf`:

```
figString = sprintf('fig%i,',1:100);
figString = figString(1:end-1); %# remove the comma at the end
```

Comment: using your method, how to generate 'fig fig fig... fig fig' 100 times? sprintf('fig',1:100) does not seem to work

Comment: @Quiang Li: Just do `repmat('fig ',1,100)`